# How to make nginx remap a part of the URL without sending a redirection?

Tags: nginx, url, mapping

I have pictures on a path looking like this:

```
/0/1/2/3/4/01234/screenshots/1.jpg
```

The URL to access it looks like this:

```
/static/0/1/2/3/4/01234/screenshots/1.jpg
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
/0/1/2/3/4/01234/a-desc-of-the-picture/screenshots/1.jpg
```

Or something similar. The goal is to have the keywords in the URL for SEO.

But would like to tell nginx to serve

```
/0/1/2/3/4/01234/screenshots/1.jpg
```

When he sees:

```
/0/1/2/3/4/01234/a-desc-of-the-picture/screenshots/1.jpg
```

I don't want it to redirect the user to the proper URL, I just want it to do the mapping internally.

Is it possible ? How can I achieve this ?

I've seen something similar [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/110361/nginx-rewrite-urls-without-redirection), but I can't find a way to apply it to my case. Something noob friendly would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you've got a base path that's regexable, you can do something like:

```
location ~ ^/static/(././././.....)/[^/]+/(.*)$ {
    alias /location/on/filesystem/$1/$2;
}
```

Nginx's [alias directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias) is more flexible than Apache's equivalent.

Comment: There is typo. Exclamation mark "!" in location statement should be replaced with tilda "~".

Comment: Thanks for that.  You can edit directly though, rather than dropping in a comment.

Comment: I can't. It prevents me from doing edits wich less than 6 characters long and I don't want to mess with other parts to overcome this limit.

Comment: How odd... I never realised there was a "minimum edit limit".  Oh well, thanks for letting me know anyway.

Comment: Cool thanks. Can you show me how to do that with lighttpd too ? I changed the title.

Comment: One question per question.  Make a separate one for lighttpd.

Comment: Fair enought :-) http://serverfault.com/questions/291394/how-to-make-lighttpd-remap-a-part-of-the-url-without-sending-a-redirection