# How to make lighttpd remap a part of the URL without sending a redirection?

Tags: lighttpd, url, mapping

Same than [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/291360/how-to-make-nginx-remap-a-part-of-the-url-without-sending-a-redirection), but for lighttpd.

I have pictures on a path looking like this:

```
/0/1/2/3/4/01234/screenshots/1.jpg
```

The URL to access it looks like this:

```
/static/0/1/2/3/4/01234/screenshots/1.jpg
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
/0/1/2/3/4/01234/a-desc-of-the-picture/screenshots/1.jpg
```

Or something similar. The goal is to have the keywords in the URL for SEO.

But would like to tell nginx to serve

```
/0/1/2/3/4/01234/screenshots/1.jpg
```

When he sees:

```
/0/1/2/3/4/01234/a-desc-of-the-picture/screenshots/1.jpg
```

I don't want it to redirect the user to the proper URL, I just want it to do the mapping internally.

Is it possible ? How can I achieve this ?